# How to find length if given one side length and one angle of a non right angle triangle

Tags: trigonometry, angle

Sorry to ask this question I am very bad in trigonometry. Can anyone help me to find length of a non-right-angled triangle if length of one side and one angle is given

Comment: Something is missing in your problem, I suspect.  For a triangle to be determined we need more than one side's length and one angle.  Perhaps you should give a more careful look at the information given in your application.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. In general, to solve a triangle you need to know Side-Side-Side, Side-Angle-Side, Angle-Angle-Side, or Angle-Side-Angle.

Your triangle is non-right-angled, so you only know 1 Side and 1 Angle. That's not enough to solve the triangle. When you know that the triangle is right-angled, that means you already know one angle. The additional one Side and one Angle information gives you Angle-Angle-Side, which is why it's possible to solve the triangle in this circumstance.